# js regex: replace a word not follows or not followed by a certain word

Tags: javascript, regex, replace

I want to replace the "word" that is outside "span", and keep the other that is inside "span". By now, the following code works when both are following "mark>" and followed by "span". But I want to go further, following "mark>" OR being followed by "span", any one of the two condition should cause replacing action.

```
var replaceString = "newWord";
var htmlString = "This <span style='color:red' title='mark'>normal word</span> need no change. This word is to be replaced. <span>Another word</span> need no change.";

var reg=new RegExp("(?!mark>)"+replaceString+"(?!<\/span>)","gi");
var bb=htmlString.replace(reg,replaceString);    
alert(bb) 

// Final result should be "This <span style='color:red' title='mark'>normal word</span> need no change. This newWord is to be replaced. <span>Another word</span> need no change.";
```

UPDATE: using title as mark. adding starting tag span

UPDATE: Follow the suggestion below, I'm trying to solve the problem in anohter way, see here: [js regex: replace words not in a span tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33080230/js-regex-replace-words-not-in-a-span-tag)

Comment: Your HTML is invalid. The second `</span>` has no starting tag. Also, what is `mark` supposed to do?

Comment: I add "mark" to mark this word had added "span", need no change again. I remove the starting tag only to describing what I want. It exists when run on real codes. Thanks.

Comment: I don't understand where the information that the word `"word"` is to be replaced is supposed to come from. Your first span contains "normal word", but you want to replace the word `"word"`?

Comment: @torazaburo, I meant "word" that is in `span` need no change, "word" may be in a sentence.

Answer (score 0):

Would you be comfortable using another `span` tag ?
By putting a class name inside it, you should be able to change the words you need to change by changing the content of every `span` containing that class.

Something like :

`This <span style='color:red' mark>word</span> need no change. This <span class='changeMe'>word</span> is to be replaced. Another word</span> need no change.`

And a jQuery script going

`$('.changeMe').text("newWord")`

If you still want to use Regexp, for an OR condition, you might just do it twice :

```
var reg=new RegExp("(?!mark>)"+replaceString,"gi");
var bb=htmlString.replace(reg,replaceString);
reg=new RegExp(replaceString+"(?!<\/span>)","gi");
bb=htmlString.replace(reg,replaceString);
```

Comment: It looks simple. Can do this with js?

Comment: Haven't use regular js in a while but
var elts = Document.getElementByClass('changeMe')
for(elt in elts){
      //Do stuff
}

Comment: yes, getElementByClass is good for knowing the class in a simple. But if it's in a large text, I need to first find out the word, and then get its class, finally replace the word. ;-( .

Comment: Well I don't know about that, but it takes what it takes. Unfortunately pattern matching in a large file is necessarily slow.
Maybe the double regex execution is better for your particular case.

Comment: I'm trying another way to get solve my problem, please take a look at the update link.

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for negative look-aheads (or Lookbehinds) which JS, unfortunately, doesn't support. Check http://www.regular-expressions.info/javascript.html

You may try the following Regex:

```
var reg = new RegExp('[^(mark>)]word[^(</span>)]', "gi")
htmlString.replace(reg, " newWord "); //Check the spaces
```

I would rather suggest using JS to get DOM elements and replace text iterative-lly (not sure if it's a word, even a jargon).

HTH

Comment: Sorry to hear that. I added a title inside `span`, can detect if the word is inside a `span` with title='mark'? How to do that? Thx.